# Why is this variable assignment throwing an error?

Tags: javascript

I am investigating an intermittent error on this `javascript` line

```
parentWindowState = window.opener && window.opener.ACME && window.opener.ACME.state
```

If you want to see the rest of the function, it's like that:

```
_doStuff:  function () {
    var someVar = '',
        parentWindowState = window.opener && window.opener.ACME && window.opener.ACME.state,
        deferred = Q.defer();

    if (parentWindowState && parentWindowState.getItem('...')) {
        //lots of code                
    } else {
        deferred.resolve();
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

A user has reported getting this error

> ```
>     Error at _doStuff (https://acme/anvils/yoloeditor/main_20160531050717.js:456321:13) 
> at Anonymous function (https://acme/anvils/yoloeditor/main_20160531050717.js:111202:37) 
> at _fulfilled (https://acme/anvils/yoloeditor/main_20160531050717.js:29048:13) 
> at Anonymous function (https://acme/anvils/yoloeditor/main_20160531050717.js:29078:13) 
> at promise.promiseDispatch (https://...
> ```

I have tried reproducing this error by debugging and setting variables `opener`, `ACME` and `state` to `null` or `undefined`, but the code will not throw an Error. It is actually supposed to handle null/undefined values.

I can only get an error like this by forcibly throwing an error like

```
 throw new Error("Boom");
```

So my question is, under what circumstances could this line throw an error?

Edit: I was trying to reproduce this error while testing with Chrome. Just realised that Internet Explorer will throw an error if ACME is undefined.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: The error stated `promise.promiseDispatch` and in this line you are writing   `deferred = Q.defer()` so logically that's the instruction firing this error.

Comment: @chsdk Sorry for me being slow here, but I don't get your point. Could you please explain with a complete  answer?

Comment: @yannicuLar from the Error it looks like `Q.defer()` is causing the problem, you have to debug it.

Comment: @chsdk Unfortunately,  I cannot reproduce this error so I cannot debug it. The error comes. from a user who copy-pasted the message from their browser

Comment: I still cannot undestand why a `Q.defer()` error would make the js code crash in this specific line.

Comment: Because it's a declaration in the same line, try to test against null for `Q.defer()` and `Q.defer().promise`;

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all this time I've been testing with Chrome, but IE will not handle this statement without throwing a 'TypeError'

I've changed the assignment as follows, and IE can handle it

```
window.opener && (typeof window.opener.ACME == 'object') && window.opener.MOS.ACME
```

I'm aware that promises can [swallow errors](http://jamesknelson.com/are-es6-promises-swallowing-your-errors/), but this is not the case here, as the above statement would throw an Error even by fiddling with IE console, or moving the statement completely outside the promised method's body. So I think that the `Q.defer()` was a red herring.